# Скрыть все меню и подсистемы в 1с

Tags: 1с

Как скрыть в 1с все элементы меню , подсистемы и прочее. Всё кроме того что есть на форме. Программно.  На кассах например у них ничего нет кроме пары кнопок.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, вам нужен режим окна "Киоск".

[Заметки из зазеркалья 1С](https://wonderland.v8.1c.ru/blog/novye-rezhimy-osnovnogo-okna/)